# How to get the values for dynamically generated input field in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hii I am new to React Js, After selecting count `InputCount`, I had generated input fields dynamically.Now I want to get the value for the inputs field and also I want to validate all the fields.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeCount = this.onChangeCount.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {,
            InputCount: "",
        }
    }
    onChangeCount(e) {
        this.setState({
            InputCount: e.target.value,
        })
    }
    render() {
            let options1 = []
            for (let j = 0; j <= this.state.InputCount; j += 1) { options1.push(j); }
            return (
        {this.state.InputCount && (
                                options1.map((i) => {
                                    return (<div>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
                                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="RollNumber" />
                                    </div>)
                                })
                            )}
```

please help me to get value from the input fields and also validate the form.

Comment: Where is `onChangeCount` used? And what `handleChange` does? You should give more clear code.

Comment: For testing i tried sir, now i edited my code please help me

Comment: The question about getting the field values is separate from the question about validating. I recommend you create a new question asking how to validate the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name input field unique by combining with the loop index.

And don't forget to use `key` when `map` item.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeCount = this.onChangeCount.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            InputCount: 2,
        }
    }
    onChangeCount(e) {
        this.setState({InputCount: e.target.value })
    }
  
   handleChange = (e) => {
     console.log('name: ', e.target.name, ' value:', e.target.value)
     // Do what you want here
   }
  
    render() {
      let options1 = []
      for (let j = 0; j <= this.state.InputCount; j += 1) { options1.push(j) }
      return (
        <div>
        {options1.map((i) => {
          return (
            <div key={`group-input-${i}`}>
              <input  onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name={`${i}-name`} placeholder="Name" /><br />
              <input  onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name={`${i}-rollNumber`} placeholder="RollNumber" />
            </div>
           )})}
        </div>
)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to get the value for the inputs field

To address each field separately, you need to name all of them uniquely. So your JSX for the fields needs to have a distinct `name` attribute for each field:

```jsx
options1.map((i) => {
    return (<div>
        <input type="text" name="name-{ i }" placeholder="Name" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="rollnumber-{ i }" placeholder="RollNumber" />
    </div>)
})
```

Now each `input` element will have a `name` attribute unique for that element. Assuming `options1` contains values 0 through 2:

- name-0
- rollnumber-0
- name-1
- rollnumber-1
- name-2
- rollnumber-2

You will get the values for the field by [interrogating the field by its `name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Using_text_inputs).